# Google Spreadsheet/ Excel - how to find matching values in column A, having necessary values in column M

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have list of product articles in column A, in the columns B to L I have additional info on the products, total 95000 lines. I also have column M which lists 3000 articles which I need to find in the list from column A. How do I highlight only matching values in column A that are present in column M?

I tried conditional formatting but the file size is too big and all actions take too much time.

Comment: Given the total number of items and your complaint that Excel with conditional formatting is too slow you need to look at other software.

Comment: @SolarMike what software you might offer? I am a rookie working with such data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
=COUNTIF($M$2:$M$5;A2)
```

it will give a 1 if the product is in the column M list, and a 0 if it isn't.
you can then filter on column N having 1.

Be mindful on your data set, the actual formula you have to use will probably be more like:

```
=COUNTIF($M$2:$M$3000;A2)
```

[image: example]